# Loading an Image Folder using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am creating an Image manipulation tool in the browser, and I want people to be able to select an Image folder to use as a directory to work from, and I would like those images to be available for editing and displaying in a HTML canvas.

How can I have the user select a folder on their computer and load all the images from inside it?

Comment: And what part are you interested in? How you can upload and load your images in the HTML?

Comment: Yes. I basically just want a user to be able to select a folder on their Computer and have all Images displayed in my website.

Answer (score 0):

What about handling Dropbox, Box, Google drive as well as File, Folder and Drag & Drop. If you are interested take a look to this: http://extract.autodesk.io/ - This sample does not work with images, but 2d/3d models, but it is not different than images, change change the file filters accordingly.

Source code is posted here: https://github.com/cyrillef/extract-view.and.data.api

Where to start:

- Install Flow.js - https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js
- https://github.com/cyrillef/extract-view.and.data.api/blob/master/www/index.html#L195 for the HTML portion
- https://github.com/cyrillef/extract-view.and.data.api/tree/master/www/js

  - upload-flow.js - using the flow.js library for local file
  - loaders.js - to handle dropbox, box, google driver, etc...
- https://github.com/cyrillef/extract-view.and.data.api/tree/master/server

  - flow-node.js - the Flow.js Node.js implementation
  - file.js - the server routing for Flow file

You also got it in PHP, if you do not want Node.js
https://github.com/cyrillef/extract-php-view.and.data.api

Comment: So I should upload the folder contents to a node.js server then re-download them to use them?

Comment: You don't have the choice, a browser cannot access local file for security reasons other than a user action for upload for example.

Comment: Thats fine. Im just concerned about the complexity of it. I thought it would be a simple javascript & php solution. Youve listed about 5 things I need.